# How to take namenode backup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, webhdfs, bigdata

I have a hadoop cluster with 6 datanode and 1 namenode. But I do not have any standby namenode or journal node. I know this is not a good practice but due to some constraints I have to continue with this for the time being.

Can any one tell me , how can I take backup of my namenode metadata manually? I have taken backup of fsimage by this command

```
hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage someFilename
```

But is this all I have to do? or I have to take a copy of **dfs.namenode.name.dir directory** also.

If fsimage  is only thing, how can we restore the fsimage if my existing namenode goes down for hardware issue.

If I have the copy of **dfs.namenode.name.dir** directory and fsimage , in that case also , how can I use those for restore purpose?

Please let me know if any one knows process to take backup and restore of namenode metadata manually.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link for the Backup of Namenode and Restoring of the Backup data:

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_mc_hdfs_metadata_backup.html